# Spring Rest Controller, but with composition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a little problem I can't work around. The idea is to have some generic controllers (and services) like this:

**GenericPagingController** class that has a method like this: 
`public ResponseEntity<Page<T1>> GetEntityPagedList(int page)`

**GenericListController** class that has a method: 
`public ResponseEntity<List<T1>> GetEntityList(int page)`

and a **GenericCrudController** with methods like this: 
`@PostMapping("") public ResponseEntity<T1> AddEntity(@RequestBody T3 entityDto)` 
`@PutMapping("/{id}") public ResponseEntity<T1> UpdateEntity(@PathVariable ID id, @RequestBody T3 entityDto)` 
`@DeleteMapping("/{id}") public ResponseEntity<String> DeleteEntity(@PathVariable ID id)`

And I want to have a base controller that uses those generic blocks something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("testing")
public class TestingController {
    private GenericPagingController<Test, TestRepository, Long> genericPagingController;
    private GenericCrudController<Test, TestRepository, Long, TestRequestDTO> genericCrudController;
    public TestingController(TestRepository repository) {
        genericPagingService = new GenericPagingService<>(repository);
        genericCrudController = new GenericCrudController<>(repository);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't want to use interfaces, because I have a plenty of pretty much identical controllers and I think using some composition stuff can work

I originally tried to extend multiple generic classes, but obviously Java can't do that.
I also tried to come up with something with interfaces, but I don't think it can work well in this case